# Python: Create an array using values and indices of a given array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

Given the following list (or numpy array):

```
x = [4, 3, 1, 2]
```

I want to generate another list (or numpy array) with 1+4+3+2=10 elements such as:

```
y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

Where `y` will have `x[i]` successive elements with a value of `i`.

Other examples:

```
x = [0,3,1]
y = [2,2,2,3]

x = [2,0,2]
y = [1,1,3,3]

x = [1,1,1,1,1]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

How can this be done efficiently? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome. It would be great if you could also include the code that you have written.

Answer (score 1):

This do the work:

```
x = [4,3,1,2]

y = []
for index, num in enumerate(x):
    for i in range(num):
        y.append(index + 1)
        
print(y)
```

or if you prefer with list comprehension in one line:

```
x = [4,3,1,2]

y = [index + 1 for index, num in enumerate(x) for i in range(num)]
        
print(y)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: @Burak Perfect! If you could mark the answer as solver would be great

Comment: @LorenzoZane another variant would be `enumerate(x, start=1)`

Comment: @LorenzoZane Btw I found the second solution the most economic in pure Python. `numpy` is a different category (`np.repeat` is >20x perfomance for large dataset).

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use `numpy`:

```
x = np.array([4, 3, 1, 2])
a = np.arange(1, x.size+1)

np.repeat(a, x)
```

Output:

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4])
```

Comment: Why `np.repeat(a, [*x])` instead of `np.repeat(a, x)`?

Comment: @mathfux - Thank you, it was redundant.  For some reason, when I originally wrote it, that method didn't work - but now it's fine.  I must have done something silly. Edited - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An unnecessarily complicated way to do this is the following, utilizing list comprehensions and the `reduce` function:

```py
from functools import reduce

def f(ls):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [[i+1]*ls[i] for i in range(len(ls))])

>>> f([0, 3, 1])
[2, 2, 2, 3]
>>> f([2, 0, 2])
[1, 1, 3, 3]
>>> f([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This is brilliant but it costs performance. It's 8 times slower than the fastest solution in pure Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [52]: alist, reps = [1,2,3,4], [4,3,1,2]
```

`np.repeat` does this kind of repetition nicely - but it makes things arrays (which takes time):

```
In [53]: np.repeat(alist,reps)
Out[53]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4])
```

List repeat can be used with:

```
In [54]: [[i]*j for i,j in zip([1,2,3,4],[4,3,1,2])]
Out[54]: [[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3], [4, 4]]
```

and the lists of lists can be flattened with:

```
In [55]: [k for l in ([i]*j for i,j in zip(alist, reps)) for k in l]
Out[55]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
In [56]: list(itertools.chain(*([i]*j for i,j in zip(alist, reps))))
Out[56]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

Some timings:

```
In [57]: timeit np.repeat(alist,reps)
10.9 µs ± 398 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

If we start with arrays, the result is much faster:

```
In [58]: %%timeit a,b = np.array(alist), np.array(reps)
    ...:  np.repeat(a,b)
    ...: 
2.97 µs ± 103 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But for this small sample, the list methods are faster:

```
In [59]: timeit [k for l in ([i]*j for i,j in zip(alist, reps)) for k in l]
2.33 µs ± 70.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [60]: timeit list(itertools.chain(*([i]*j for i,j in zip(alist, reps))))
2.46 µs ± 76.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

For larger cases, I expect the [58] times to scale the best.  I'm not sure about the others.